# Returning true or false when searching for individual characters in an array

Tags: javascript

What is the best method of searching through an array for individual characters and returning true if found and false if not using JS?

For example:

```
search["adipisci","adipiscix"]
```

returns **false in array element 1** and **true in array element 2** when **"sciipx"** is searched

Many thanks!

Comment: So it should return true only when all characters in the search word are located in the array element?

Comment: Yes only when all characters in the search word are located in the array element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
var search = "sciipx".split('');
var elems = ["adipisci","adipiscix"];
var matches = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var found = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < search.length; j++) {
        if (elems[i].indexOf(search[j]) < 0) {
            found = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        matches.push(i); // you can do elems[i] if you prefer
    }
}
```

In the end matches will be an array with indexes of strings that matched.
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Xvy/

NB: If you need it, the loops can be further optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @draevor. Can matches be alerted this way: `if (found) {
        matches.elems[i]; // you can do elems[i] if you prefer
        alert(matches);
    }`

Comment: Sorry I meant to write what should I do to get the output of matches... is it just `alert(matches)`?

Comment: Lastly, I just want to ask about `elems[i]`... what does it do? Not sure if I'm using it correctly... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/W3Xvy/)

Comment: In the fiddle page I do `console.log(matches)` - that will print the array. If you do `alert(matches)` it will show you the index numbers - just try it. If you do `matches.push(elems[i])` then doing `alert(matches)` will show you the strings that matched - just give them a try on the jsfiddle page.

Comment: Ok thanks! Are there any other alternative methods apart from `push` that I can use?

Comment: Alternatives doing what? `push` simply adds the matched index (or string) to the array of matched elements. If you just want to see the matched strings, just replace `matches.push(i)` with `alert(elems[i])`.